# Trouble with generating a signature for Yahoo API

Tags: python, yahoo-api

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to sign my Yahoo API calls. I'm being rate-limited to 2000/hr because my calls are currently unsigned (I think). I have a Yahoo API key, along with the access tokens associated with authenticating my app. I'm confused because OAuth 2.0 does not require signatures anymore (https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/) so as long as I have the API key, in theory I should not be limited.

Yahoo's responsiveness is next to zero on these issues and their documentation has not been updated in years. Wondering if anyone has had similar issues related to their API limits.

I'm using yahoo-auth for my authentication/requests without any issues (https://github.com/josuebrunel/yahoo-oauth).